# A word for the feeling that only last a few moments

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm searching for a word if you guys can help me find it.. It is the moment when for ex: you are just about to jump out of an airplane (with parachute x) ) or when the song hits THAT great note.. Or when a horse rears when you are on it.. Or any moment that only lasts for a few seconds after a longer build up..

I can't find a good word that would describe it.. closest I have found is word like 'epiphany' or 'Climax' or 'Eureka'.

Comment: Depends to a degree on whether it's good, bad, or indifferent.  "Fleeting" sensation of some sort is one, "flash", "flush", or "rush", perhaps.

Answer (score 10):

Are you referring to a 'fleeting' moment?

Comment: Or a momentary thrill of some sort.

Comment: Moment *noun*: a very brief period of time.

Answer (score 4):

It gave me a **thrill**

> - "a sudden feeling of pleasure or excitement"
> - "a quivering or trembling caused by sudden excitement or emotion." [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thrill)
> - "a sudden sharp feeling of excitement" [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thrill)

- "Vegas has enough high speed coasters and other **thrill** rides to leave you more thoroughly shaken than a pair of maracas."
- "Drivers who speed, who violate other rules of the road, and who seek **thrill** when driving pose greater crash risk to themselves.
- "He always had a **thrill-seeking** behavior.
- "For nobody else, gave me **a thrill**,

  With all your faults,   I love you still

  It had to be you,  wonderful you, It had to be you.

(It Had to Be You", a popular song written by Isham Jones, with lyrics by Gus Kahn)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to officially propose "rush".

Third definition in the third definition of [Websters Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rush):  *a surging of emotion*

(It's also apparently the name of some sort of musical combo.)

Comment: This has been flagged; I'd add a reference.

Answer (score 1):

OP seeks a word which captures the essence of a few extraordinary (i.e., *non-mundane*) experiences which, while fleeting and brief, are yet of enduring import and influence. Although words like *epiphany*, *climax*, and *eureka* are often applied to such emotionally-charged experiences, because the OP is dissatisfied with those words, it would seem that their synonyms would be equally unsatisfactory. I will suggest one word and two short phrases:

> **MOMENTOUS** *adjective*: (a decision, event, or change) of great importance or significance, especially in its bearing on the future; of unparalleled significance
>
> **Synonyms**: important, significant, historic, portentous, critical, crucial, life-and-death, decisive, pivotal, consequential, of consequence, far-reaching, impactful, earth-shattering, earth-shaking;
>
> English Wiktionary
>
> **MOMENT OF TRUTH** *noun* (idiomatic): a deciding instant; the time when a test determines or makes it apparent whether something will succeed.
>
> **1**. the point in a bullfight when the matador faces the bull for the kill
>
> **2**. a critical moment or time that tests and reveals one's true self or makes one face the truth (***The moment of truth comes when you jump out of an airplane (with or without a parachute!***)
>
> **Origins**:
>
> A calque of Spanish *el momento de la verdad*, which refers to the time of the final sword thrust in a bullfight.
>
> English Wiktionary
>
> **PEAK EXPERIENCE** *noun*:
>
> 1. a high point in the life of a self-actualizer, during which the person feels ecstatic and more alive and whole than is usual.
>
> **What is a peak experience?**
>
> **Abraham Maslow**, the term's inventor, says that "*peak experiences are sudden feelings of intense happiness and well-being, possibly the awareness of an "ultimate truth" and the unity of all things ... the experience fills the individual with wonder and awe....he  feels at one with the world, and is pleased with it* ...." They are moments when you feel more at one with yourself and the world, more integrated. You feel happy, even ecstatic, interconnected and in harmony. Peak experiences are one type of mystical experiences, and perhaps one of the most interesting in that Maslow aims to talk about mystical experiences in non-supernatural terms
>
> [**Peak Experience**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_experience)

Answer (score 0):

Those are very different situations... Perhaps you are searching for the word ***"pinnacle"***?

Answer (score 0):

*ecstasy* ?

*elation* ?

Also off the top of my head, I'd say *ephemeral euphoria*.  A lot of e-words.

I think you're trying to describe two different qualities here.  One is temporal: that it's brief, then disappears, would be *ephemeral* or *transient*.

The second quality is the sensual nature of the feeling.  In sex, music or literature, it's a *climax*, but that has a different nature than the *rush* of adrenaline or the *excitement* of anticipation, *satiating* thirst or hunger,  *savoring* an excellent meal, or the *intoxication* of alcohol.

*Epiphany* and *eureka moment* are generally reserved for flashes of insight, invention and/or genius or the occurrence of great ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Epiphany. ( relates to 'Eureka')

Reference: Wikipedia

An epiphany (from the ancient Greek ἐπιφάνεια, epiphaneia, "manifestation, striking appearance") is an experience of sudden and striking realization. Generally the term is used to describe scientific breakthrough, religious or philosophical discoveries, but it can apply in any situation in which an enlightening realization allows a problem or situation to be understood from a new and deeper perspective.